# android com.facebook.catana post on wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i need to create method for create post on wall on facebook (the post format is String). I would like use app facebook on device with android. I have method for messenger, whatsapp, twitter. But with facebook app i have problem. I have this code:

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
 sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Some text");
 sendIntent.setType("text/plain");


 PackageManager packManagerFB = getPackageManager();
 resolvedInfoList = packManagerFB.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

 for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolvedInfoList) {
 if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.facebook.katana")) {
    sendIntent.setPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
    break;
   }
}
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Problem is that text area in facebook app from EXTRA_TEXT is empty.
Thank you for advice.

Comment: you can have a button to open Messenger app.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow prefilling of text, so the EXTRA_TEXT value is ignored